# Creating a copy of another a range object in Word using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, copy, range, alias

In Word, I tried this:

```
Dim Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range
Set Range1 = Selection.Range 'just an example, could be any range
Set Range2 = Range1 'seems to create an alias, not an independent copy
Range2.Collapse 'Not only collapses Range2, but also Range1
Range1.Select 'I had rather keep te original Range1 unaffected
```

How do I create an independent copy of Range1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to create two Range objects that point to the same location in the document but can be manipulated independently of each other use

```
Set Range2 = Range1.Duplicate
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.duplicate

Comment: Great, thanks! I already found out al alternative:
Set Range2 = Activedocument.Range
Range2.SetRange Range1.Start, Range1.End

but your solution is really what I was looking for